# Android: Enabling last Spinner in ListView and disabling the rest.

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner

I am using customize ListView in which there is a Spinner.

Code:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/lightGray2"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerPaymentType"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="17" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eTextPaymentAmount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="7"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPaymentDetail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="6" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

There is a button(Suppose buttonA) which is out side ListView and after clicking on this button one row get added in ListView.

Now I want to disable all other row spinner when I click on the buttonA.

Suppose already three row was there and before adding fourth row in ListView I want to disable spinner which is inside first three row.

Adapter getView Code:-

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    System.out.println("*** getView() ***");
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);

    Spinner spinnerPaymentType = (Spinner) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.spinnerPaymentType);
    EditText eTextPaymentAmount = (EditText) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.eTextPaymentAmount);
    eTextPaymentAmount.setText(String.valueOf(position));
    btnPaymentDetail = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnPaymentDetail);
    btnPaymentDetail.setTag(position);
    btnPaymentDetail.setOnLongClickListener(this);

    btnPaymentDetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("*** btnPaymentDetail is clicked");
            getPaymentDetail();
        }
    });

    ArrayList<PaymentType> aListpaymentTypes = new ArrayList<PaymentType>();
    for (int i = 0; i < paymentCollection.get(0).getaListPaymentOptions()
            .size(); i++) {
        aListpaymentTypes.add(new PaymentType(paymentCollection.get(0)
                .getaListPaymentOptions().get(i).getIntPaymentId(),
                paymentCollection.get(0).getaListPaymentOptions().get(i)
                        .getStrPaymentType()));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<PaymentType> aAdapterPaymentType = new ArrayAdapter<PaymentType>(
            context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            aListpaymentTypes);
    aAdapterPaymentType
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerPaymentType.setAdapter(aAdapterPaymentType);
    spinnerPaymentType.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: @W.K.S...I know the code will be in getView method. How I disable the spinner.

Comment: To disable the spinner you write `spinner.setEnabled(false)`.If you can paste your getView() method, I can give you an idea about how to do this?

Comment: I updated and added getView method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are expanding this layout in the `getView()` method of an ArrayAdapter. In this method, you can check whether the current list item is the last one and if it isn't, disable the spinner. When you add a new item, invalidate the ArrayAdapter so that the list is redrawn.

**UPDATE**

Try adding this line before returning rowView:

```
//if spinner is last spinner, enable. Otherwise disbale.
spinnerPaymentType.setEnabled( (position == this.getCount()-1) );
```